# Failure when trying to deploy a model

Tags: python, streamlit

i am trying to load a model on pycharm saved for prediction but i am getting the below error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

what could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

The [scikit-learn](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) module is not installed in your python environment